# Pandas Increment Rolling Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am trying to accomplish an incremental rolling date increase in python/pandas using the following conditions:

- I have a pandas dataframe with two columns and want to insert a new column where the first row is a specified date.
- Each following row increments the previous row's date by one calendar day.

For example:

```py
# example data frame
import pandas as pd 

# create DataFrame 
data = {'c1':[5, 3, 8, 7, 15], 'c2':[20, 21, 19, 18, 19]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df 

# example start date
pd.to_datetime('Nov 4, 2010')
```

Each row represents one day's worth of data.  I also have a specified start date, in this case, Nov, 4th, 2010.  Which corresponds to the first row in the dataframe, and is supposed to increment by one day for each row, which gives the following output:

[image: output table]

I know this is trivial to do in Excel, by selecting a cell with a date and dragging it down (sorry, know I went there) but for some reason the same operation in pandas seems to more challenging.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('Nov 4, 2010'),periods=len(df))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

```
maxsize = len(df)
pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('Nov 4, 2010'),periods=maxsize)
```